# Get exact phone number from a TON NPI prefix number in android?

Tags: java, android, telephony, libphonenumber

I have several phone numbers that have `TOA = TON + NPI` as the prefix.
Some of these numbers are like 
1217006529482
148015206427
1415615032525
The TOA in these cases are 12, 11 and 14 respectively.
How do I resolve the exact number by passing these numbers as strings?
I tried some API's from [PhoneNumberUtils.java](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.java) but unable to figure out the right method.

Comment: Have you tried using substring method to create substring of the original string excluding the TOA ?

Comment: I do not wish to strip the TOA as I have some cases like, 148015206427 and 1218015206427. I guess the TOA information creates some difference between the two cases.